# How to embed an authorize.net payment gateway form into a single page website with one item for sale?

Tags: authorize.net

My website sells one item. I am currently using the simple checkout button embedded on the website. Rather than having the button I would like the order form to be on the single page with a field for quantity.

At first I imagined that there would be a simple form that I could embed however it looks like that I need a full integration into my website through the Advanced Integration Method (AIM) which is much more complicated then I wanted.

I don't want integration into my website, can I do it without, and if I have to what is the cleanest and simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Server Integrated Method](http://developer.authorize.net/api/sim/). It uses Authorize.Net's own secure server to handle the payment form and processing the credit card.

You can also use [Simple Checkout](http://developer.authorize.net/api/simplecheckout/). As its name implies it is a very basic and simple option for selling items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script which integrates with auth.net and has a very simple form

http://codecanyon.net/item/authorizenet-payment-terminal/234122?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=Convergine